# Why is my jscolor color picker not working properly?

Tags: html, css, jscolor

I have downloaded the latest version of jscolor.js (2.05), but have had some problems when using it. In CSS, I have been trying stop displaying the value of the color on the button. I tried using 'valueElement: null;' but I get an 'Unknown Property' error for valueElement. I since found out that 'borderWidth','backgroundColor', and 'insetColor' all also throw the same error.

Because valueElement is not recognized, I have no way of disabling the color value over the button.

I suspect this has also caused the picker to be offset when it is opened in the webpage. The rainbow in the middle of the rectangle seems to be offset within the overall picker. Here is a link to a picture of the problem:  (https://ibb.co/9N8dHXs)

How do I disable the color value on the button, and what is causing all of these properties to not be recognized?

```css
  .jscolor {
            border: white;
            width: 50px;
            position:'right';

            valueElement: null; /*throws 'Unknown Property' error*/
            shadow: false;
            borderWidth:0;   /*throws 'Unknown Property' error*/
            backgroundColor:'transparent'; /*throws 'Unknown Property' error*/
            insetColor:'#000'; /*throws 'Unknown Property' error*/
            padding: 0;
        }
```

```html
<div class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
            <div>
                <h4 class="sect-head">BACKGROUND</h4>
                <div class="sect-child">
                    Sky Color
                    <input class="jscolor" onchange="setRendererColor(this.jscolor)" value="FFE4A6">
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a closer look at their examples page, here: http://jscolor.com/examples/ and search for the "Linking to different elements" example, you'll find exactly what you need.

From what I can tell, there are 3 differences between their code for a button and yours. I suspect the first is irrelevant.

1. They used a `button` and you used an `input type='button'`
2. In the class attribute, they also supply what appears to be json - you only supplied the jscolor class
3. You've given the element a value - this is both printed and used as a background
   color
4. You're using an event handler to update the colour of the button.
5. When the user has pressed it, it's given the class jscolor-active **instead** of jscolor - therefore, your css no longer applies. Instead, you may wish to add another class to the button in addition to jscolor. That way - the javascript can still identify and manipulate elements and your added class will remain untouched and thus, your css will continue to apply.

Here's your code:

```
<input class="jscolor" onchange="setRendererColor(this.jscolor)" value="FFE4A6">
```

And here's theirs:

```
<button class="jscolor
    {valueElement:'valueInput', styleElement:'styleInput'}">
    Click here to pick a color
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't really solve my problem. If you go to "Custom Look" in the examples section, I am using the same 'input' tag as them, instead of using the 'button' tag, so it should still work. Also, where did you see that they put a json? Also, I tried the separate class, but it still only affects the button and not the picker itself. I have also provided a link to how my color picker has glitched: [link] (https://ibb.co/9N8dHXs)

Comment: Okay, I'm now unclear about your desires. Lets get them ironed-out, shall we? You say you want to "stop displaying the value of the color on the button" - that could mean two things. Do you wish to hide the *text* e.g: "#FF0000", or do you wish that the button does not become red? What is it you'd like to do to the picker with CSS? You did not mention this wish in the original question. I answered the question you asked. Did you mean to ask something else?

Comment: I'm sorry about the confusion, I basically had a problem I wanted to fix which led me  to stumble on a bigger problem, that I also want to figure out.  1. I want to do the former of what you described, 'hide the text e.g: "#FF0000".' 2. Then when I was trying  to figure this out, I found that 'valueElement' and a few other properties throw an unknown property error. 3. I then think that my second question might have to do with why I have this glitch on the color picker (the one I send the link of the image for).   Thank you so much for helping me, sorry I wasn't being super clear

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code that show you how to do it correctly with the `input`:

```js
generated_button = document.querySelector("#generated-button");
function update_font_color(jscolor) {
    // 'jscolor' instance can be used as a string
    generated_button.style.color = '#' + jscolor
}
```

```html
 <body>
 <div id="generated-button-div">
       <input id="generated-button" type="button" value="Default Label">
 </div>
 <div class="input-wrapper">
       <label for="font-color">Font Color:</label>
       <input name="font-color" id="font-color" class="jscolor {onFineChange:'update_font_color(this)'}" value="000000">
 </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jscolor/2.0.4/jscolor.js"></script>
 </body>
```